# How to update/Patch Kube-proxy config?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rancher, kube-proxy

I am using Rancher for Kubernetes Installation and cluster Management. For fixing issue related to IP Tables I need to update the cluster-cidr attribute in Kubeproxy config (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/36835 ), I am not sure how to update the kube-proxy. Can someone tell me how to update it via Kubectl or UI or how to login to kubeproxy and chnage it?

Answer (score -2):

if we are talking about the `Kubernetes`:

1. find the directory `/etc/kubernetes` on your node
2. there will be some files and directories, you need to find where the manifests store (something like `kube-proxy.manifest`, which is a .yml file )
3. open it and there you'll find `--cluster-cidr`, it is an option to `command`:

`command:
    - /hyperkube
    - proxy
    - ...
    - --cluster-cidr=<your_CIDR>`

(actually `command` is a list in YAML implementation, and the `--cluster-cidr` is a member of this list)

Note: depending on deploying tool (including the `Rancher`) this directory structure/file names might be different